# How to select the right node value using xsl:if

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have 2 different XML

**1 XML**

```
<address>
    <localityType>CityType</localityType>
    <locality>CityName</locality>
</address>
```

**2 XML**

```
<address>
    <localityType>TownType</localityType>
    <locality>TownName</locality>
</address>
```

And I have a XSLT stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
            <title>Address</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>City</td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:variable name="loc" select="//localityType" /> 
                            <xsl:if test="$loc = 'CityType'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="//locality" />
                            </xsl:if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Town</td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:variable name="loc" select="//localityType" />
                            <xsl:if test="$loc != 'CityType'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="//locality" />
                            </xsl:if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And as the result I want to get for the first XML the following table
[image]

And as the result for the second XML - the following table
[image]

My problem is that I don't get this tables because of my **xsl:if** statement. Maybe I'm using them wrong

Comment: You will have to edit your query, because the tables you mention are not being displayed. It's not clear what the issue actually is.

Comment: Please show a complete XSLT stylesheet - otherwise there's no way to diagnose the problems (e.g. because we do not see the template match).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But the problem was that I didn't wrote `$` before my variable `loc`. Someone already posted this as an answer and while I checked it, he removed the answer.

Comment: Not really. The problem is very different - you _don't_ need a variable at all and your code is very badly written. If you post more context, someone can suggest improvements.

Comment: I updated the `XSLT`, but I didn't add something interesting. I'm not telling that my code is the best, but I need only use `if` to choose where to display `locality`. And it will be great if you give me some tips to upgrade my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stylesheet below yields the same HTML output, without using `xsl:variable` or the `//` axis. The fact that those constructs are available in XSLT does not mean you should use them in any situation.

**When to use `xsl:variable`**

You should use a variable

- when not using it would mean repeating a long-winded expression in several places
- to store any contextual information that you need in another context
- to store an intermediate result before moving on to the next step of the transformation

Your usage of `xsl:variable` falls in neither of those categories: the expression is simple, the element `localityType` is readily available in the context and you don't need the result for later.

**When to use `//` (the descendant-or-self:: axis)**

You should use `//` only if the structure you are navigating with this expression is *not* statically known. In your case, the structure of the input XML is not exactly deep and known beforehand. Your template match is for `/` and you know the full path to the `localityType` element: `"address/localityType"`.

Using `xsl:if` is a good idea.

---

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/address">
        <html>
            <head>
            <title>Address</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>City</td>
                        <td> 
                            <xsl:if test="localityType = 'CityType'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="locality"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Town</td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:if test="localityType = 'TownType'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="locality"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Assuming the following input XML:

```
<address>
    <localityType>CityType</localityType>
    <locality>CityName</locality>
</address>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Address</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
         <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>CityName</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Town</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Rendered HTML**

> [image]